# How to get and set a Hyperlink in a class

Tags: c#, xml, api, gridview

I am getting an XML list of concerts from Jambase API, I also have a class called event.cs .  I run a loop putting the data from XML into Event objects.  I then bind a gridview to an ArrayList of Event objects.  There is a string for "band", "venue", "date" ect.

The problem is I want one column to be HyperLink's that all say "info" and when you click it , it is the url for that specific event.  I don't want to display the actual URL.  I tried this, but no luck.

```
  // this is from Event.cs
    public string Venue
     {
       get { return venue; }
       set { venue = value; }
     }

    public HyperLink Info
     {     

        get { return info; }
        set { info = value; }
      }
```

//this is where I load the XML into ArrayList

```
    XmlDocument xmlEvent = new XmlDocument();
             xmlEvent.Load(string.Format("http://api.jambase.com/search?band=       {0}&apikey={1}&n=30", BandName, key));
             ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

             foreach (XmlNode node in xmlEvent.SelectNodes("JamBase_Data/event"))
             {
                Event event1 = new Event();
                 event1.Date = node.SelectSingleNode("event_date").InnerText;
                 event1.Location = node.SelectSingleNode("venue/venue_city").InnerText + ", " + node.SelectSingleNode("venue/venue_state").InnerText;
                 event1.Venue = node.SelectSingleNode("venue/venue_name").InnerText;
                 event1.Info.Text = "more info";
                 event1.Info.NavigateUrl = node.SelectSingleNode("event_url").InnerText;
                 al.Add(event1);

             }
             return al;
```